# Magento 2 - URLs trailing slash redirection programmatically

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, redirect-url

I want to redirect automatically any url that comes as example.com/ to example.com or example.com/men/ to example.com/men

Could someone point me to the right direction.

I do not want to modify htaccess.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should try two options:

1) modify htaccess (you don't want to do it)

2) Setup URL Rewrites: **MARKETING > URL Rewrites**.

Comment: is 2nd option possible for cms pages please advise